# Call to pixel.quantserve.com fails from time to time recently

Tags: bug

I'm not sure if it's just me but recently when I refresh SO pages, it seems to take long time (not always, but fairly often). I checked what was failing and it turns out that it's a call to `pixel.quantserve.com`.

Is it just me or is it a general problem?

[image]

---

As requested, this is my trace route:

```
Tracing route to anycast-asia.quantserve.com.akadns.net [203.190.124.21]
over a maximum of 30 hops:

  1     2 ms     3 ms     1 ms  home.gateway [192.168.1.254] 
  2    17 ms    15 ms    13 ms  nme-nxg-wal-bras4-lo-20.tpgi.com.au [10.20.20.224] 
  3    20 ms    15 ms    17 ms  nme-sot-dry-crt2-Te0-2-2-0.tpgi.com.au [202.7.162.54] 
  4    16 ms    16 ms    16 ms  59-100-192-173.mel.static-ipl.aapt.com.au [59.100.192.173] 
  5    18 ms    16 ms    17 ms  te3-3.mburndist02.aapt.net.au [203.131.61.32] 
  6    16 ms    15 ms    18 ms  te0-3-1-0.mflincore01.aapt.net.au [202.10.12.17] 
  7    17 ms    16 ms    17 ms  te2-2.mflindist01.aapt.net.au [202.10.12.10] 
  8    17 ms    16 ms    15 ms  te2-1.mflinbrdr01.aapt.net.au [202.10.14.11] 
  9    15 ms    15 ms    17 ms  tengigabitethernet7-3.lon77.melbourne.telstra.net [139.130.41.105] 
 10    17 ms    19 ms    15 ms  bundle-ether3.exi-core1.melbourne.telstra.net [203.50.80.1] 
 11    32 ms    32 ms    30 ms  bundle-ether5.way-core4.adelaide.telstra.net [203.50.11.92] 
 12    65 ms    62 ms    64 ms  bundle-ether5.pie-core1.perth.telstra.net [203.50.11.17] 
 13    63 ms    59 ms    59 ms  gigabitethernet0-7-0-0.pthp-core01.perth.net.reach.com [203.50.13.246] 
 14   165 ms   171 ms   158 ms  i-1-1-0.6ntp-core01.bx.telstraglobal.net [202.84.141.45] 
 15   165 ms   179 ms   166 ms  i-0-6-1-2.hkth-core01.bx.telstraglobal.net [202.84.143.166] 
 16   169 ms   172 ms   199 ms  i-0-2-0-0.hkhh01.bi.telstraglobal.net [202.84.143.42] 
 17   155 ms   154 ms   154 ms  unknown.telstraglobal.net [134.159.100.70] 
 18   155 ms   154 ms   153 ms  quantcast-35.mpr2.hkg001.pnap.net [202.56.10.54] 
 19   156 ms   153 ms   153 ms  203.190.124.21 

Trace complete.
```

Comment: It happens to me quite often, but randomly - I don't think it's anything we can fix. I just chalk it up to (latency/traffic/wonky wifi/etc) - generally refreshing (or just requesting the page again) cures it for me.

Comment: I generally just do nothing as SO works fine without it. It's just that the spinning wheels constantly moving in Chrome are a bit annoying. Also, wasn't sure if it's not something you guys should be made aware of.

Comment: Probably worth asking, as the times you posted are _much_ longer than what I've experienced - curious to see if anyone else is seeing it.

Comment: Can you post a traceroute to `pixel.quantserve.com`?

Comment: @NickCraver I've added that.

Comment: @Szymon thanks, I'll let them know you're having issues.  Not to say you can't do the same, we just usually get some eyes on it quicker with the `@stackoverflow` email in the from field ;)